# GSON vs ObjectSerializer Efficiency

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist, gson

I currently have a class which extends `arraylist` and implements `parcelable`, which allows for it to be passed through intents.

While this is useful, I wish to hold the objects in the arraylist while the user exits the app, and was thinking to use SharedPreferences to do so.

As arraylists cannot be directly passed into shared preferences, I have noticed two popular methods are to parse it using either `GSON` or `ObjectSerializer`. However, I have also heard both are rather expensive. Which begs the question, which one is more efficient for this purpose? Is there another method(aside from sets, as I am developing for froyo) which is better suited?

Comment: Not really performance related, but I found it a lot easier to deal with class changes when I didn't have to deal with default java serialization (which is what `ObjectSerializer` seems to use behind). For me, GSON was more resilient and if all else fails you can easily modify the generated JSON data.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) you can see a detailed article that compares serialization tools